# Names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, convention

```
var A = function () {
    this.someProperty = 0;
};

var a = new A();
```

The variable `a` is an object. What do I call to `A`? A class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A` is called a *constructor function*. Well, specifically, `A` is a variable that refers to a constructor function, but we don't usually get into that kind of mintuiae.

Sometimes people do call these "classes," because constructor functions aid in producing *classes* of objects (in the general sense, e.g., objects with common characteristics). But JavaScript doesn't have classes in the class-based OOP sense like Java or C#, it has a different inheritance mechanism called *prototypical inheritance*. (This is true even in ES2015 and beyond, where the keyword `class` is used to define a constructor function, the properties of the prototype it assigns objects when used with `new`, and sometimes properties on that function referring to other functions ["static methods"].)

Comment: It's very weird to call it a function, especially if I also change `A.prototype`.

Comment: @SlySherZ: It's not weird at all, it *is* a function. :-) `typeof A` is `"function"`, it inherits from `Function.prototype`, etc. `A.prototype` is just a property on that function (functions are objects, so they can have properties) that's used by the `new` operator when constructing the object to pass into it when you do `new A`. If you don't use `class` to create it, you can even call it without `new` and do something different from when it's called with `new` (I recommend *not* doing that, but you can). (Ones created with `class` can only be called via `new` or `super`.)